# Django How to link a foreign key to many tables

Tags: python, django

I have n classes and each class contains a column called  **key** like this (where n==3)

```
class class1(models.Model):
    Id1 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 16, blank=True)

class class2(models.Model):
    Id2 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 16, blank=True)

class class3(models.Model):
    Id3 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 16, blank=True)
```

I want to make the column  **key** as Foreign key between all the n classes?
I know how make a foreign key between 2 classes but I want to do that with many classes because I have about 40 classes and some classes has some commun columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-1) to make a Foreign Key to a generic model. You need to use the `ContentType` framework, write your models like:

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class class1(models.Model):
    Id1 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class class2(models.Model):
    Id2 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then when you create a `class1` instance, you could make a Foreign Key to a `class2` (or another model) instance with:

```py
class1_instance = class1.objects.create(content_object=class2.objects.get(id2=1))
```

Then you can access the `class2` instance with:

```py
class1_instance.content_object
```